# Rails 4 + Datatables: Ajax-datatables-rails gem will not update table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, datatable

I am trying to use the `ajax-datatables-rails` gem found [here](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails) with no luck.  My table shows up, and has the right data (for the first page), but when I attempt to search, sort, or change pages, no table data gets updated.

**Am I missing something simple?**

**View**

```
<table id="users-table" data-source="<%= users_path(format: :json) %>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Admin?</th>
      <th>Employee?</th>
      <th>Client?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
    format.json { render json: UserDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
end
```

**Datatable**

```
class UserDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  # uncomment the appropriate paginator module,
  # depending on gems available in your project.
  # include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::Kaminari
   include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::WillPaginate
  # include AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions::SimplePaginator

  def sortable_columns
    # list columns inside the Array in string dot notation.
    # Example: 'users.email'
        @sortable_columns ||= [
            'users.id', 
            'users.name',
            'users.email',
            'users.admin',
            'users.employee',
            'users.is_client'
        ]
  end

  def searchable_columns
    # list columns inside the Array in string dot notation.
    # Example: 'users.email'
        @searchable_columns ||= [
            'users.id', 
            'users.name',
            'users.email',
            'users.admin',
            'users.employee',
            'users.is_client'
        ]
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        # comma separated list of the values for each cell of a table row
        # example: record.attribute,
                record.id, 
                record.name, 
                record.email, 
                record.admin, 
                record.employee, 
                record.is_client
      ]
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    # insert query here
        User.all
  end

  # ==== Insert 'presenter'-like methods below if necessary
end
```

**js**

```
$('#users-table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $('#users-table').data('source')
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    // optional, if you want full pagination controls.
    // Check dataTables documentation to learn more about
    // available options.
});
```

Comment: Is your `$('#users-table').dataTable()` call in DOMReady callback?

Comment: yes, and its with a bunch of other functions being called successfully.  The chart loads, it just wont update, and the ajax requests all look identical

Answer (score 0):

You have server side processing enabled which means that datatables will make an ajax request when you search or sort and pass a set of parameters via the url you specified in your ajax options.

The actual processing has to be done on the server and the response has to conform to the protocol as specified by datatables. You can consult the docs [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data)

Comment: I understand that, but this gem is supposed to help make those ajax requests as far as I can tell...

Comment: Ah sorry didn't see you were using the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using singular 'user.id' instead of 'users.id' in your UserDatatable class for all your columns. I had to do this for mine which would not accept the typical plural naming convention of my table as shown in the documentation for this gem.

Comment: You should be able to check to see if that's an issue by calling the `users_path{ format: :json}`. E.g. if users_path is `/users` then calling `localhost:3000/users.json` should show you a json formatted datatable. If that shows I doubt it's the `UserDatatable` that's the issue.